# AWS Cognito Change Password .Net Core 3 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, amazon-cognito

We're using AWS Cognito for user accounts and using their hosted login form.  Today I realized that there is not a "Change password" feature anywhere I can find on the Cognito Hosted Web UI.  Is this true? If it is I need to figure out how to build a change password form.

The app is built in .NET Core 3.1, and I have added the `AWSSDK.CognitoIdentityProvider` NuGet package.

I get an access token after a user logs into Cognito and is redirected back to my app via OpenIdConnect.  In my `Startup.cs` I have this code inside `.AddOpenIdConnect()`  which is within `ConfigureServices()` which I thought was giving me an access token for the user:

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
{
    OnTokenValidated = context =>
    {
        // Access Token
        var accessToken = context.SecurityToken.RawData;

        var option = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions();

        option.Expires = new DateTimeOffset(context.SecurityToken.ValidTo);
        context.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("CognitoAccessToken", accessToken, option);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
}
```

Then in another request, I get that same token and pass it into `ChangePasswordAsync`:

```
var cognitoClient = new Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient("admin-level-access-key-id", "admin-level-secret-access-key");

var testClientWorks = await cognitoClient.DescribeUserPoolAsync(new Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.Model.DescribeUserPoolRequest { UserPoolId = "...my pool id..." });

var token = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["CognitoAccessToken"].ToString();
var response = await cognitoClient.ChangePasswordAsync(new Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.Model.ChangePasswordRequest
{
    AccessToken = token,
    PreviousPassword = "oldpassword",
    ProposedPassword = "Test1234$"
});
```

The call to `DescribeUserPoolAsync` works, so I know the credentials for the `cognitoClient` are valid.  But the call to `ChangePasswordAsync` fails with the error 'Invalid Access Token'.

So, if the access token I get back when they log in is not good, where do I get a valid one?

Edit:

So it turns out that I have an ID token and not an access token.  I think this is because of how I configured OpenIdConnect.  Changing `options.ResponseType` to `token` like below results in an error: `Exception: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty`.

```
options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
options.Authority = $"https://cognito-idp.{awsCognitoRegion}.amazonaws.com/{awsCognitoPoolId}";
options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
options.ClientId = awsCognitoClientId;
options.ClientSecret = awsCognitoSecret;
//options.ResponseType = "code"; //what I was using before
options.ResponseType = "token";
options.UsePkce = true;
//options.Scope.Add("profile");
//options.Scope.Add("offline_access"); //results in invalid scope error
options.Scope.Add("openid");
//options.Scope.Add("aws.cognito.signin.user.admin");
options.SaveTokens = true;

////Tell .Net Core identity where to find the "name"
options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress";
options.TokenValidationParameters.AuthenticationType = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
////options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier";

options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
options.ClaimActions.Clear(); //fixes something in .NET Core
```

This is how the OAuth 2.0 section is configured in Cognito:

[image]

Comment: Can you print the access token to make sure it is a JWT token indeed? Try decoding it at jwt.io. Among other fields it should have `"token_use": "access"`.

Comment: It does decode at jwt.io, but only has `"token_use": "id"`.   So, is this a different scope I need to request (and maybe turn on in AWS Cognito)?

Comment: Or is there a way to request an access token from `CognitoIdentityProvider` with the id token?

Comment: @MaxIvanov I added more info to the original post.

Comment: For server side apps you should go with `code` oauth flow as it's more secure. The code is exchanged for ID Token, Access Token and Refresh Token. So if you have ID token in your code, I'm quite sure there must be access token as well.
Sorry can't help with the code beyond that as I know nothing about .NET.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the tokens were being set behind the scenes somewhere.  So you can request them after login via:

```
var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);
var refreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken);
var idToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken);
```